# Extract first element with XPath and scrapy

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I use `.extract()` to get the data from a xpath, like:

```
response.xpath('//*@id="bakery"]/span[2]/text()').extract()
```

the issue with this is that I always get a list as response.
for example:

```
['23']
```

I only want the number, so I try with:

```
response.xpath('//*@id="bakery"]/span[2]/text()').extract()[0]
```

but this is a problem is the list empty, although I can use an exception to handle that scenario I guess there is a better way to do it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`.extract_first()` to the rescue:

```
response.xpath('//*@id="bakery"]/span[2]/text()').extract_first()
```

Instead of an exception, it would return `None` if no elements were matched.

Answer (score 6):

There is a new Scrapy built in method `get()` can be used instead of `extract_first()` which returns a string or `None` if no element exists.

```py
response.xpath('//*@id="bakery"]/span[2]/text()').get()
```